# Language code 'en' not removed from URL

Tags: seo

I'm trying to set up a multilingual site for Danish and English (US) languages. I've turned on the option "Remove URL Language Code" in the Language Filter plugin. This does remove the "da" codes from the Danish page URLs, but the English page URLs still contain "en".

Danish is set as the default language.

I've renamed the URL language code for US English from "en-us" to just "en". I tried renaming it back again, but that didn't help.

The site is running on IIS, if that's relevant.

Here's the URL: http://modesty.dk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remove language code refers to the site's default language. You can't remove the language code for all languages, as if we suppose something like this would be allowed by the plugin, you would end up with the same URLs for all languages and there would be no way to distinguish on which language and what kind of content you are requesting/looking at.

The language code (on SEF URLs) is the request that tells Joomla that you are requesting another language. So you can't live without it. Plus it also helps with creating a physical organization on your site's structure.

So, again what this feature does is to remove the language code only for the default language, something that is a valid requirement for a multilingual website.

Comment: Yes, as I indicate when I answered my own question, I do now realize that this is how it works.

Comment: "You can't remove the language code for all languages, as if we suppose something like this would be allowed by the plugin, you would end up with the same URLs for all languages and there would be no way to distinguish on which language and what kind of content you are requesting/looking at." Well, Joomla could save an indication of which language is currently being used by each connection. Have there been any efforts to provide that kind of functionality in Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I've discovered that this is how it's supposed to work. I found the answer here:
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=812094